# Swap two annotations by drag&drop

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

Is it possibile to swap two annotation on a MKMapView?

I made the MKAnnotationView draggable with:

```
self.draggable = YES;
self.animatesDrop = YES;
```

and implemented the `-setCoordinate:` method of the correspondent `MKAnnotation`.

I can drag&drop the annotation on the map but now I want to swap it with another one on the same map. What I mean is when I drop the annotation it should check if there is near another annotation, if there swap their coordinates.

Is it possible? How?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Don't expect to receive a fully functional code without showing us what you have tried and what are exactly the issues you're facing.

Comment: The big problem for me is in the setCoordinate. When it is called I can change the coordinate of the annotation I'm dragging but I can't access the annotations on the map to see if there is one near the one I'm dropping.